# How do I fill a javascript editor?

Tags: javascript, delphi, browser, autofill

I use `TEmbeddedWebBrowser` to fill a html form using `FillForm` method. But my html form contains a fully javascript based editor and i don't know how to fill that.

Something like this :

```
your comment :
<script type='text/javascript' src='public/scripts/src/editor.js?1'></script>
```

And the submit btton :

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" class="btn" onclick="rtevalue(&quot;data[body]&quot;,437934);" />
```

Comment: Thank you, The example have used `SetFieldValue` method. But as i said the problem is that there is no field in the form. Editor is js-based. how can i find its field?

Comment: I tried to fill the `iframe` using `innerHtml` and `innerText` properties but I got this error : Member not found. it seems the `iframe` doesn't have these properties.

Comment: And the `IHTMLElement` class doesn't have `execCommand` method.

Comment: @Kermia, Show us the `javascript` source or a link to it, and your Delphi code also... BTW, when you reply to a comment use `@` followed by the user name, so he/she will get notified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The editor itself is a `DIV` (could be other HTML element) or `IFRAME` set to `contentEditable / designMode` = `on`.
If the element is a `DIV`you could use it's `InnerHTML` property.
For the best results with an `IFRAME` use the below code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  editorDoc: OleVariant;
  range: OleVariant;
  id: OleVariant;
begin
  id := 'editor'; // frame ID
  editorDoc := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow.frames.item(id).Document;
  range := editorDoc.body.createTextRange();
  // range.collapse(false); // if you need to append
  range.select();
  range.pasteHTML('<b>Boo!</b>');
end;
```

Notes:

- No error checking to simplify the code.
- You might also try `range.execCommand('inserthtml', false, MyText)` (Not tested with `TEmbeddedWebBrowser`, but had bogus results when I tried it with plain `HTML`/`Javascript` on `IE`).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience concerning this TEmbeddedWebBrowser tool, but according to your post I'm thinking of a way to retrieve the form's fields. Once you know what fields it contains, I suppose you can fill them as it doesn't seem to be the purpose of your post.

1. Assuming there is a form declared and it is reachable: you can grab the form and
   parse its `.elements` collection: easily if it's declared in your page
   (give it an `id` attribute, then use a `document.getElementById()`),
   it may still be doable if the form is declared by/inside
   `editor.js`, using `document.forms` then.
2. Otherwise: you can get a dump
   script from the Net - like [this one](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php) -
   and see what is printed when you call (after including `editor.js`
   naturally) `dump(data)` or `dump(data[body])`. As `data[]` is
   used as an argument to the `rtevalue()` called by your submit button's
   `onclick`, it should contain the form's key/value pairs. The bad thing about this method is that `data[]` must
   be filled by Javascript, so if your form has radio buttons or
   checkboxes you may only see the selected ones, which is why I would give a shot at the first option before trying this trick.

About the comments, you should not directly use `innerHTML` to insert an HTML subtree to the document as most of the times it doesn't work (especially when forms are involved), have an `appendChild()` redo the work to ensure a correct document, like this:

```
var dummyContainer=document.createElement("span");
var dummyContainer.innerHTML="..."; //insert stuff here, because it's easy to use ;)
myContainer.innerHTML=""; //clearing your "real" container doesn't add anything to the HTML tree, it'll work - you can also use removeChild() in a loop (but it's not as easy to use!)
myContainer.appendChild(dummyContainer); //appendChild will translate properly the text inserted by innerHTML in dummyContainer into a clean HTML subtree
```

Comment: Can you give us an example/reference when `innerHTML` doesn't work to insert an HTML subtree? what's wrong with `myContainer.innerHTML="<span>whatever</span>"`?

Comment: @kobik I know that from my own experience (years ago, but if I used a shrink I'd regulary tell him/her about that), I wasted days trying to understand why that stupid innerHTML didn't do its job. First, and to answer your question, I just googled "innerHTML insert issue", and found - among other pertinent results - this interesting article: http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99 Second, quoting W3Schools at http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp "innerHTML is not a part of the W3C DOM specification.", i.e. there are other spec-friendly ways to alter the HTML tree (appendChild...)